# Bypass proxy not working on Nexus 5 running lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, proxy

In my wifi network I need to connect to the internet through a http proxy. I am able to connect to the internet through the proxy server but the problem lies when I want to access my local servers. To access the local servers I need to bypass the proxy. So while connecting to the wifi connection in the bypass proxy section I specified a list of local hostnames for which I need to bypass proxy server but still I am unable to access those local sites. Any solution? (without rooting my phone as it is still in warranty).
Thanks in Advance!